# How to INSERT INTO SQLite with SELECT FROM SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I want to SELECT a table in a SQL Server database and then INSERT it into a local SQLite database.

IS it possible to do this entirely with a query in the vein of:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

but passing connection information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a local odbc data source, DSN, for SQLite file. Call it SQLite_DataSource

Then setup a linked server in SSMS:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'SQLite', -- the name you give the server in SSMS 
   @srvproduct = '', -- Can be blank but not NULL
   @provider = 'MSDASQL', 
   @datasrc = 'SQLite_DataSource' 
GO
```

Then you can use it like any other db:

```
INSERT into SQLite_DataSource (column1)
SELECT col1
FROM table2
```

Lookup SQL Server's documentation for sp_addlinkedserver for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SQL Server Linked Server to SQLite, take a look at this [post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3087/creating-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-sqlite-to-import-data/) for more information .